# calling qSort on a an array using Qt qSort()

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5.8

I have a dynamic array.

`int* array = new int[size]`

I am using the Qt library to develop an application in C++11.

Can I use `qSort` from `QtAlgorithms.h` on it this way:

`qSort(array, array+size-1)`

I am not sure since the arguments require a type of `RandomAccessIterator`

Does that imply any pointer ?

Comment: If you're using `c++11` then `std::sort(array,  array + size)` is probably a better option.

Comment: `qSort` is stated as obsolete. also the end of range means actually out of range for both `qSort` and `std::sort` so `array+size` is the proper index for the end.

Comment: @AlexanderVX what do you mean obsolete ? I am referring to the qSort that is part of the Qt library

Comment: Qt company apparently maintains some algorithms only for the backward compatibility: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtalgorithms-obsolete.html#qSort They imply: use STL for that.

Comment: ok thanks guys. Should be a simple swap. I can just call `std::sort` instead

Comment: @marc Consider creating an answer yourself. It may be useful for others with the same question.

Comment: Use std::vector instead of new[].

Answer (score 0):

`qSort()` has been deprecated since Qt 5.2. Quoting from the [ChangeLog](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/dist/changes-5.2.0/?h=v5.2.0):

> With STL no longer being optional for building and using Qt, a number
>   of parts of QtAlgorithms no longer make sense, and have therefore been
>   deprecated.
>
> Replacements are available in the STL, and generally have much
>   better   performance, but are not instantly source-compatible in all
>   cases. For   instance, specialization of qLess or qSwap means that a
>   direct port to   std::sort from qSort may not be possible, as
>   std::sort does not use any of   them; a possible workaround is... [see
>   link for more info].

Note that as the ChangeLog mentions, there are cases where a trivial find/replace is not sufficient.

For some discussion on the differences in speed of `std::sort()` and `qSort()`, see [here](https://phabricator.kde.org/D10857).

These are just warnings now, but will [likely be errors](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-73048) with Qt 6.